# How to configure Jetty settings in project.clj and use Lein Ring in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, jetty, leiningen, embedded-jetty

I would like to add some configuration to Jetty Adapter and run it with the lein-ring plugin, but i could not find any information.

I can run this configured from the main function by using `lein run`.

```
(jet/run-jetty main-handler {:port 8080 :join? false})
```

But I want to set those configurations in the project.clj so I can use "`lein ring server`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lein-ring documentation](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring) suggests you can put a map of options for your ring adapter in the project.clj file, like this:

```
:ring {:handler hello-world.core/handler
       :adapter {:join? false
                 :port 8080}}
```

Though you probably do not want to use `:join? false` I'd think.